How to be able to access all folders on Ubuntu when using Visual Studio Code Remote?
I have my user which seem to be in the sudo group:
myuser@server:~$ groups myuser
myuser : myuser adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev

But when I use Visual Studio remote with SSH, it doesn't give me the option to view all the folders.
It only let me view up to my user's home folder.
How can I be able to view everything? I specifically want to navigate to /var/www but simply don't have the option
Also, I clearly don't have permissions even though I'm in the sudo group because I can't for example run mkdir somedir in /var/www so I assume it's permissions issue (But how come I am in the sudo group?)

Being allowed to use sudo, i.e., superuser do, is not the same as actually using that command. As admin, you can install software, e.g., sudo apt install wine32, but you must start that terminal session  with sudo (which stays operative for a time). To make a folder at a higher level than /home, use sudo mkdir.
